# JAVA Programming Generics

Tags: java, generics

On generics **method** Why we use **void** after **generics** Type **T**? while Generics return the type which will  passed on it.

Comment: Can you please provide an example for illustration?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean. A code-sample would be helpful or at least using Java-terminology.

Comment: The only valid thing I can think you mean is something like `<T> void doSomething()`. You use `void` there because it's the return type; `<T>` is the declaration of a type variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is generified method which returns boolean:

```
public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2)
```

There is generified method which returns void:

```
public static <K, V> void compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2)
```

There is generified method which returns K:

```
public static <K, V> K compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2)
```